# Border around text with page of full formulas

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, border

I am trying to frame a text with `\fbox` and make `auto-newline` before or in the text. Currently, my formulas are out of the margin when they are too long (Sometimes there is text, not only formulas). [image: border around text]

Part of my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm,left=0.1cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%boxx
\newcommand{\boxx}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
%matrix
\newcommand{\mtx}[2]{\ensuremath{{\binom{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
...
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \mtx n{n-k}$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \frac nk \mtx{n-1}{k-1}$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \mtx{n-1}{k-1} + \mtx{n-1}k$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{i}{k}\mtx{k}{j} = \mtx{i}{j} \mtx{i-j}{k-j}$} 
\boxx{$(x+y)^n = \sum^n_{k=0} \mtx nk x^{n-k}y^k$} 
\boxx{$\sum^m_{n=k}\mtx nk = \mtx{m+1}{k+1}$} 
\boxx{$(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_t) = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\dots k_n!}$} 
\boxx{$(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_t)^n = \sum_{k_1+k2+\dots+k_t=n}(k_1,\dots,k_t) x_1^{k_1} , x_2^{k_2}, \dots, x_t^{k_t}$} 
\boxx{$(1+x)^n = \sum^n_{p=0}\mtx np x^n$}
\boxx{$(1+x)^{-n} = (\frac{1}{1-x})^n = \sum^n_{p=0}\mtx {n+q-1}q x^q$} 
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try tcolorbox package

Comment: welcome to tex.se. to help you we should see your code (in form of small, complete document, beginning with`\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. otherwise we can only guessing or give some general advice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please don't just show parts of your code, but take the time and create a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)!

Comment: This is the main code, putting everything is not necessary because it is composed only of `\boxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `\noindent\raggedright` at the beginning of the document.  The `\noindent` to prevent indentation on the 1st line, the `\raggedright` is useful when typesetting large horizontal blocks, which otherwise tend not to align with margins (if you did not want `\raggedright`, `\sloppy` might be an alternative, in which case the gaps would be distributed between boxes rather than at the end of the line).

No additional breaking mechanism is needed, because you provide an implied space between your `\fbox`es by putting one per line.  If that space were absent, you would need an `\allowbreak` between `\fbox`es to permit the line break between boxes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm,left=0.1cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%boxx
\newcommand{\boxx}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
%matrix
\newcommand{\mtx}[2]{\ensuremath{{\binom{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\raggedright...
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \mtx n{n-k}$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \frac nk \mtx{n-1}{k-1}$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{n}{k} = \mtx{n-1}{k-1} + \mtx{n-1}k$} 
\boxx{$\mtx{i}{k}\mtx{k}{j} = \mtx{i}{j} \mtx{i-j}{k-j}$} 
\boxx{$(x+y)^n = \sum^n_{k=0} \mtx nk x^{n-k}y^k$} 
\boxx{$\sum^m_{n=k}\mtx nk = \mtx{m+1}{k+1}$} 
\boxx{$(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_t) = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\dots k_n!}$} 
\boxx{$(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_t)^n = \sum_{k_1+k2+\dots+k_t=n}(k_1,\dots,k_t) x_1^{k_1} , x_2^{k_2}, \dots, x_t^{k_t}$} 
\boxx{$(1+x)^n = \sum^n_{p=0}\mtx np x^n$}
\boxx{$(1+x)^{-n} = (\frac{1}{1-x})^n = \sum^n_{p=0}\mtx {n+q-1}q x^q$} 
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is what it looks like with `\raggedright` replaced by `\sloppy`:

[image]

And here is what it would look like with `\raggedright` but `\boxx` defined as `\newcommand{\boxx}[1]{\fbox{#1}\allowbreak\ignorespaces}`

[image]

Comment: Wow. awesome. This is exactly what I needed in detail! Thanks a lot